# jq null unix timestamps parsing issue

Tags: bash, jq, unix-timestamp, strftime

I'm trying to parse a big json file which I receive using curl.

By following [this answe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36853325/10854998)r I could parse the next file:

```
$ cat test.json 
{"items": [{"id": 110, "date1": 1590590723, "date2": 1590110000, "name": "somename"}]}
```

using the next command:

```
TZ=Europe/Kyiv jq -r '.[] | .[] | .name + "; " + (.date1|strftime("%B %d %Y %I:%M%p")) + "; " + (.date2|strftime("%B %d %Y %I:%M%p"))' test.json
```

Output is:

```
somename; May 27 2020 02:45PM; May 22 2020 01:13AM
```

But when I try to parse the next file using the same command:

```
$ cat test2.json 
{"items": [{"id": 110, "date1": 1590590723, "date2": null, "name": "somename"}]}
```

Output is:

```
jq: error (at test2.json:1): strftime/1 requires parsed datetime inputs
```

I could replace those null values using `sed` by some valid values before parsing. But maybe there is a better way to skip (ignore) those values, leaving nulls in output:

```
somename; May 27 2020 02:45PM; null
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could tweak your jq program so that it reads:

```
def tod: if type=="number" then strftime("%B %d %Y %I:%M%p") else tostring end;

.[] | .[] | .name + "; " + (.date1|tod) + "; " + (.date2|tod)
```

An alternative would be:

```
def tod: (tonumber? | strftime("%B %d %Y %I:%M%p")) // null;

.[] | .[] | "\(.name); \(.date1|tod); \(.date2|tod)"
```

Comment: I'd suggest putting the jq program in a file (say: program.jq) and running it with `jq -r -f program.jq test.json` .   If you still run into a problem, please specify which alternative is causing the problem.