# Convert epoch columns to human readable format

Tags: bash, awk

I am using bash script to output data to a text file. The output file has first two columns that are in epoch format and I am trying to figure out how to add to the bash script to convert those columns into human readable format.

My script:

```sh
aws backup list-recovery-points-by-backup-vault --backup-vault-name "${VAULT_NAME}" --query "reverse(sort_by(RecoveryPoints, &RecoveryPointArn))[*].{RecoveryPoints: RecoveryPointArn, CreationDate: CreationDate, CompletionDate: CompletionDate}" --output table > getList.txt
```

Sample Output from getList.txt:

```
|  1607750797.22 |  1607749558.24 |  arn:aws:backup:us-west-1:010101010101:recovery-point:z0ab4c11-000d-4aaa-v01d-100z27zz32ab   |

|  1610688137.88 |  1610687158.08 |  arn:aws:backup:us-west-1:010101010101:recovery-point:a01q84c9-2035-1234-baf7-8aaa35aa111a   |
```

How can the output of the 1st and 2nd columns be converted into human readable format during exporting to  getList.txt? Can I use something like following in the script:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"}{$1,$2=strftime("%c",$1, $2)} {print}'
```

Any help and suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: If you set the output to json instead of table, this looks like it might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36853202/jq-dates-and-unix-timestamps

Comment: Except for trying to do both conversions at once, that awk code is not unreasonable on its face. If you split it into two separate assignments, it would look plausible to me.

Comment: please add "awk" tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to do the columns one by one. Also note that since the lines start with a `|`, the first date is in field 2 (not 1).

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|";} 
         {$2 = strftime("%c", $2); $3 = strftime("%c", $3); } {print}' < foo.txt 
|Sat 12 Dec 2020 07:26:37 AM EET|Sat 12 Dec 2020 07:05:58 AM EET|  arn:aws:backup:us-west-1:010101010101:recovery-point:z0ab4c11-000d-4aaa-v01d-100z27zz32ab   |
|Fri 15 Jan 2021 07:22:17 AM EET|Fri 15 Jan 2021 07:05:58 AM EET|  arn:aws:backup:us-west-1:010101010101:recovery-point:a01q84c9-2035-1234-baf7-8aaa35aa111a   |
```

Or something like this if you want to avoid repeating the `strftime()` call (it's not even shorter here, but anyway):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"; cols[2]=cols[3]=1} 
         { for (i in cols) $i = strftime("%c", $i) } {print}' < foo.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. I can get the following command to work:  gawk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|";} 
         {$2 = strftime("%c", $2); $3 = strftime("%c", $3); } {print}' < foo.       So, its reading my output file foo and converting into human readable form.

Answer (score 0):

In bash, you can call date commande:

```
~$ date -d @1607750979.22
Sat Dec 12 06:29:39 CET 2020
```

`-d` to specify a date instezd of now
`@epoch` to input a date as epoch

Comment: That's specific to GNU date, not to bash. It'll run on systems without bash if they have GNU date, but not necessarily on systems without GNU date even if they do have bash. (Try it on a Mac that hasn't had GNU coreutils installed, f/e).