# jq: convert milliseconds to date

Tags: jq

I need to convert seconds to date:

My input documents are:

```
{"_id":"ae53d3ec-8fc3-44fc-a7eb-f2f32da4eaae","birthDate":{"value":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"-469929600000"}}}}
{"_id":"ef92c3e4-d5d7-4b81-8a0b-1ab1eac10331","birthDate":{"value":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"-854755200000"}}}}
```

I need to get:

```
{"_id":"ae53d3ec-8fc3-44fc-a7eb-f2f32da4eaae","birthDate":"1955-02-10"}
{"_id":"ef92c3e4-d5d7-4b81-8a0b-1ab1eac10331","birthDate":"1942-12-01"}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jq dates and unix timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36853202/jq-dates-and-unix-timestamps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.birthDate |= (
   .value."$date"."$numberLong" |
   tonumber |
   . / 1000 |
   strftime("%F")
)
```

With `-c`, this produces the desired output exactly.

```json
{"_id":"ae53d3ec-8fc3-44fc-a7eb-f2f32da4eaae","birthDate":"1955-02-10"}
{"_id":"ef92c3e4-d5d7-4b81-8a0b-1ab1eac10331","birthDate":"1942-12-01"}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/vA8nhNBl_Q) on jqplay

Comment: `%F` can be replaced with equivalent `%Y-%m-%d`

Answer (score 2):

Grab the source value, chop off the last three digits to turn the number into seconds and call `todate` to convert it into a date string (GMT).

```sh
jq -c '.birthDate |= (.value."$date"."$numberLong"[:-3] | tonumber | todate[:10])'
```

```json
{"_id":"ae53d3ec-8fc3-44fc-a7eb-f2f32da4eaae","birthDate":"1955-02-10"}
{"_id":"ef92c3e4-d5d7-4b81-8a0b-1ab1eac10331","birthDate":"1942-12-01"}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/kzs7QGawM_)